# Regular Expression. Repeat a schema

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

```
Literal text1: XXXXX Literal text2: XXXXX
```

Where XXX are text with an unknown length and unknown chars, may be numbers, may be chars or symbols.
This string with the same literal text could be repeated for X times like so:

```
Literal text1: XXXXX Literal text2: XXXXX
Literal text1: XXXXX Literal text2: XXXXX
Literal text1: XXXXX Literal text2: XXXXX
Literal text1: XXXXX Literal text2: XXXXX
...
```

Is there a regular expression that could match regardless of the number of rows and get all the XXXXX fields regardless of the amount of values to get.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is what you'd use whatever kind of 'global match' functionality your regex flavor has. (For instance, in Python it's `re.findall`; in Perl it's `/.../g`.)

Example in Python:

```
import re

for match in re.findall(r"Literal text1: (.*?) Literal text2: (.*?)", your_str):
    # Do something with the match
    print match.group(1)
    print match.group(2)
```

Comment: I wanna to avoid a cycle .I want a regular expression that matches 1 string ..But each time I'll pass to that regular expression a different string with a different amount of repeated rows (1 or 100) , it will match that string.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9e807fx.aspx Use `Regex.Match ()`and then keep calling `.NextMatch()` on the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..This is a good approach..But suppose that the string is more complex..Not only repeated strings but also other random strings and that the Regular expression is generated programmatically..I cannot generate a loop programmatically. I wanna that similar lines will be matched by the regular expression and define a rule so that 1 similiar line or more lines all matches the same rule.

Comment: Add a .*? to the end then (to grab any intervening text) and then wrap it all in a group and add a `+` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question, but using back-references, this regex will match anything where the XXXXX is the same XXXXX in each matched line:

```
(\w+) text1: (.*?) \1 text2: \2
```

eg this will match

```
abcd text1: foo abcd text2: foo
```

And '$2' will be the capture `foo`

Comment: I wanna do something like this [text1: (.*?) text2: (.*?) ]* (repeat the preceding schema for x times) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Instead of reading till the end of the line with `$`, you could read unitl the next row starts with `Literal`

This could work too `Literal\s*\w+:\s*(.*?)Literal\s*\w+:\s(.*?)Literal`

Group 1: XXXXX for text1.

Group 2: XXXXX for text2.

Comment: ok..but what if the string has a variable number of rows ?..I wanna that it will match always regardless of the number of rows the string contains.